# Fix button to stay disable until user checks a checkbox as well

Tags: javascript

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" onsubmit="return ValidationEvent()">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="js-email" name="email" value="<?=formDisplay(getSessionValue("er_email"))?>" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" class="js-zip" name="zip" value="<?=formDisplay(getSessionValue("er_zip"))?>" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="js-name" name="firstname" value="<?=formDisplay(getSessionValue("er_first"))?>" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="js-lname" name="lastname" value="<?=formDisplay(getSessionValue("er_last"))?>" required>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="js-pass" name="password" required>
    <input type="password" id="confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="js-pass" name="confirm" required>
    <span class="textLeft flex alignCenter terms">
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="yes" required>
        <span>
            <span>I agree</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="textLeft flex alignCenter terms">
        <input type="checkbox" name="term" value="yes">
        <span>
            <span>Keep me posted</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <center>
        <input class="disabled white cbtn1 c1" type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="START MY ORDER" disabled>
    </center>
    <?php 
    unset($_SESSION['er_email']);
    unset($_SESSION['er_zip']);
    unset($_SESSION['er_first']);
    unset($_SESSION['er_last']);
    ?>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {

                empty = true; 
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#submit-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled').removeClass('orangeBtn');
        } else {
            $('#submit-btn').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled').addClass('orangeBtn');;
        }
    });
})()
```

As you can see from the image, the button gets enabled once you enter all the input fields, I tried with my javascript above for it to also be display until I check "I agree", even if the "keep me posted" was unchecked, but for some reason the it gets enabled before the user clicks "I agree" , how can I fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: note (i like notes): don't forget to add the same code (named function?) for the checkbox `click` event, or else the button will stay disabled if the checkbox click is made at the very end, after all fields are filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if empty or checkbox not checked keep it disabled.

```
if (empty || !$('input[name="terms"]').is(':checked')) {
    $('#submit-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled').removeClass('orangeBtn');
} else {
    $('#submit-btn').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled').addClass('orangeBtn');;
}
```

You are checking if inputs have values. the checkbox has a value "Yes" so it validates as true.

Comment: where do I add this in my javascript?

Comment: note: there is a `'` missing after `[name="terms"]`

Comment: @Kaddath Thank you

Comment: I changed the name & it still didnt work, it worked as normal

Comment: @sarah I missread, The names in the question to differ, so it's ok, no need for change. You only need to change your if else to mine if else

Comment: Now it just stays disabled

Comment: @sarah check my comment under the general question, if you click on the checkbox last, this is normal, you need the code in the checkbox click event too. But it should work if you check first, then fill the fields

Comment: I put it inside my function I didn't make them two separate ones

Comment: @sarah what i mean is that all this verification is done only when you fill a text field (`keyup` event on them). It will not be done yet when you check or uncheck the checkbox. for that you should implement a `$('input[name="terms"]').click(function(){ /*basically the same code, but in this case $(this) will be a differenet element */ });`

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have skipped if checkbox is checked or not, so you have to add that check too:

```
var checkbox = $('form > input[type=checkbox]:checked').length; 
 $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '' && checkbox == 0 ) {

                empty = true; 
            }
        });
```

Comment: it didn't work , i got the same output that i got before

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example of how to enable and disable a button.
This might help you implement your logic.

```js
$("#testCheckBox").click(function(){
  if(this.checked) {
    $("#testBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#testBtn").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="testCheckBox">
<button id="testBtn" disabled="true">Click It</button>
```

Comment: I have 2 checkboxes, and I just want to click one

Comment: Apply this logic to that checkbox only.